# Java Game Dev: Sprite sheet frame by row and column?

Tags: java, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to get the X and Y coords of the frames of an animated sprite sheet by giving it the frame width, height, rows, columns, and frameCount. Then I want it to give me back what row and column number the frame is in given a frameNumber. (counting from top to bottom right to left)

I realized that I could get the column number (if I consider the rows and columns to be represented by an `int[][]`) just by doing `frameNumber % rows` but I'm stumped on how to get the row number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have cols columns, you can simply use:

Use:

```
row = Math.floor(frameNumber / cols);
col = frameNumber % cols;
```

so if you have 1000 cols and want frame number 3989 it would give you:

row = 3;
col = 989;

Comment: I thought about this but I wasn't sure, does the Math.floor operation round down to the nearest full integer even if the number is closer to the next biggest integer? Like does 1.99999 turn out to be 1?

Comment: yes, it always floors. thats why you need it in this case. (actually only in the / not in the modulo)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the width and height of the frames, how many frames per row there are, and which frame you want, than getting the x and y coordinates is fairly simple:

```
    frameX = ((frameNumber - 1) % columns) * frameWidth;

    frameY = ((frameNumber - 1) / columns) * frameHeight;
```

Note that the '/' operation must be an **int**, **short**, or **byte** division, as you need the remainder to be rounded off to get the X and Y coordinates at the *beginning* of the frame, as opposed to somewhere in the middle.

These formulas are for a sprite sheet where the frames go from left to right, then top to bottom.  If you want it the other way around, than just switch the '%' and '/' operators, and change 'columns' to 'rows':

```
    frameX = ((frameNumber - 1) / rows) * frameWidth;

    frameY = ((frameNumber - 1) % rows) * frameHeight;
```

This is also assuming that you will be referencing your frames starting at 1, however if you instead index them starting at 0, than the '- 1' portion can be removed:

```
    frameX = (frameNumber % columns) * frameWidth;

    frameY = (frameNumber / columns) * frameHeight;
    //assuming that frameNumber indexes from 0;
```

Also, if you just want to know which column or row the frame is in, than just remove the '* frameWidth' and '* frameHeight' portions, which will return row and column indices starting at 0:

```
    frameX = (frameNumber - 1) % columns;

    frameY = (frameNumber - 1) / columns;
```

Hope this helps.
Zistack

Comment: I don't think the part for finding frameY is correct, I just end up with a decimal.

Comment: Like I said, it has to be an int, byte, or long division, so that the decimal is truncated.  If you are still having a problem, than cast the entire expression back into one of the aforementioned types.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this answer is confusing so I have to downvote it.